# What's the joke behind the "Naruto" hat for Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, winterbash-2014

[One of the hats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZYYI.png) for [Winter Bash 2014](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) is titled "Naruto", and has the description

> post an accepted answer that receives no other votes for 12 hours

Having never watched *Naruto*, I'm curious what the joke here is.

(Should this go here or on the main site? Beats me; migrate if you see fit.)

Comment: Maybe it should go on MSE? I don't know. I don't get it either, but I've also not seen the series.

Comment: maybe because Naruto want to be Hokage and didn't have any friend at first? I don't really understand either

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Naruto was (eventually) accepted even though he was lonely for most of his childhood. I'm guessing it's something like that. Probably one of Oded's conceptions.

Comment: Guilty as charged. It is essentially the Tenacious badge.